# Selenium select window does not work if new window is opened from link/button inside the iframe

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

My Dom structure is like

```
 <iframe id="frame1">
       <input type="button" onclick="openModalPopup"></input>
   </iframe>
```

When I cick on this button inside the iframe, selenium opens the modalpopup , but it is not able to move the control there?

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the default frame( remove focus from the current frame), and then try to move your control to the popup.
That should work.

Answer (score 0):

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html.  Search for iframe in the reference.  You would need to selectFrame..Only then you can interact with it.